# Efficient method for creating a last day of month variable

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of date strings (e.g., "2003-11"). Creating a series of dates with the first day of the month is straightforward:

```
data['firstday'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

I have not figured out how to create a series of dates with the last day of the month efficiently.  What I have is:

```
data['lastday'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
for i in data['date'].index:
  data['lastday'][i] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'][i])+MonthEnd()
```

This works but seems clunky to me.  Is there some better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `apply`, e.g.:

```
data['lastday'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).apply(lambda x: x + MonthEnd())
```